# regex not working correctly when the test is fine

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

For my database, I have a list of company numbers where some of them start with two letters. I have created a regex which should eliminate these from a query and according to my tests, it should. But when executed, the result still contains the numbers with letters.

Here is my regex, which I've tested on https://www.regexpal.com

```
([^A-Z+|a-z+].*)
```

I've tested it against numerous variations such as SC08093, ZC000191 and NI232312 which shouldn't match and don't in the tests, which is fine.

My sql query looks like;

```
SELECT companyNumber FROM company_data 
WHERE companyNumber ~ '([^A-Z+|a-z+].*)' order by companyNumber desc
```

To summerise, strings like SC08093 should not match as they start with letters.

I've read through the documentation for postgres but I couldn't seem to find anything regarding this. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Thanks.

Comment: Try `WHERE companyNumber NOT SIMILAR TO '[A-Za-z]{2}%'`

Comment: Thank you, that worked. If you can, could you perhaps explain why that did work and my regex didn't perhaps?

Comment: Your regex probably doesn't do what you intend - `[^A-Z+|a-z+]` will match a *single* character that is neither a lowercase letter nor an uppercase letter nor a literal `+` nor a literal '|' .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `~ '([^A-Z+|a-z+].*)'` does not work because this is a `[^A-Z+|a-z+].*` regex matching operation that returns true even upon a *partial* match (regex matching operation does not require full string match, and thus the pattern can match anywhere in the string). `[^A-Z+|a-z+].*` matches a letter from `A` to `Z`, `+,`|`or a letter from`a`to`z`, and then any amount of any zero or more chars, anywhere inside  a string.

You may use

```
WHERE companyNumber NOT SIMILAR TO '[A-Za-z]{2}%'
```

See the [online demo](https://rextester.com/MODV4489)

Here, `NOT SIMILAR TO` returns the inverse result of the [`SIMILAR TO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP) operation. This `SIMILAR TO` operator accepts patterns that are almost regex patterns, but are also like regular wildcard patterns. `NOT SIMILAR TO '[A-Za-z]{2}%'` means all records that start with two ASCII letters (`[A-Za-z]{2}`) and having anything after (`%`) are NOT returned and all others will be returned. Note that `SIMILAR TO` requires a full string match, same as `LIKE`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. If you can, could you perhaps explain why that did work and my regex didn't perhaps?

Comment: @KieranDee I hope I added enough details. I think `SIMILAR TO` is the best fit for your task. If your conditions become more specific, you may consider moving to the `~`  operator. Then, do not forget about `^` to mark the start of string and in case you need that, `$` as the end of string anchor.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. So even if any part of the string matches the regex, postgres will return it basically. Meaning I have to match the entire string with the regex rather than part of it, at least for my regex.

Answer (score 2):

Not start with a letter could be done with

```
WHERE company ~ '^[^A-Za-z].*'
```

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0bf1fec7bd90888b11dbc34b1f632655)

The first `^` marks the beginning. The `[^A-Za-z]` says "no letter" (including small and capital letters).

---

**Edit:** Changed `[A-z]` into the more precise `[A-Za-z]`  ([Why is this regex allowing a caret?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926))

Comment: `[^A-z]` does not actually mean no letter. It means ``no letter, [, \, ], ^, _ and ` chars``. See [the `[A-z]` char range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes of course you're right. In that case the other solution is wrong as well because it starts always with a digit. Thats when the TO no exactly defines its use case.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern: `[^A-Z+|a-z+].*` means "a string where at least some characters are not A-Z" - to extend that to the whole string you would need to use an anchored regex as shown by S-Man (the group defined with `(..)` isn't really necessary btw)

I would probably use a regex that specifies want the valid pattern is and then use `!~` instead.

```
where company !~ '^[0-9].*$'
```

`^[0-9].*$` means "only consists of numbers" and the `!~` means "does not match"

or

```
where not (company ~ '^[0-9].*$')
```